# Ubuntu 12.04 stuck on loading screen. How can I save my data?

Tags: 12.04, data-recovery, windows-vista

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 since months, but from one day to another Ubuntu is not booting anymore.
I installed it with Wubi under Windows Vista. How can I save the data I have on my Ubuntu? I tried different tools to enter my linux system through windows, but I don't see any Ubuntu files.

I already tried Linux Reader and Ext2Fsd. I think the reason why I am not seeing my files from the ubuntu system is because there is no such partition.

Best Denis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wubi indeed does not create a partition but creates a file in your Windows partition and mounts it as a loopback device (a way for Linux to access a file as if it was a partition).

The file should be under program files, under wubi or ubuntu folder (depends on the version of wubi, it's been a while since I used it).

You can boot the system with an Ubuntu live CD/USB, access the windows partition from the Ubuntu live system, it should be one of the accessible filesystems on the launcher.

In the Windows filesystem find the Ubuntu "drive" file under program files, and then do the following in the terminal (ctrl+alt+t launches a terminal):

```
sudo mkdir /media/wubi
sudo mount -o loop,ro /path/to/ubuntu/file /media/wubi
```

Replace the "/path/to/ubuntu/file" with the location of the "drive" file.

Now you should be able to see a filesystem that is your Ubuntu drive and can copy/upload/email whatever you want from it.

Keep in mind, that your Windows filesystem may be read only on a 12.04 live system, and that by following my instructions, the Ubuntu filesystem is also read-only.